# Form UpdateView and DeleteView and 3 hierarchical models

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an 'Expense Tracker'. I have query regarding UpdateView and DeleteView and Models with 3 hierarchical levels. I was able to create the CreateView for the 'Expense' model,  but the update and delete view are throwing a lot of errors. Can you please tell how to write the code for update and deleteview (for 'Expense' model).

Models.py

```
class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=year_choices()
                              ,validators=[MinValueValidator(1984),
                               max_value_current_year], name='year',
                               unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.year)

    class Meta():
        ordering = ('-year','-year')


class Month(models.Model):
    month = models.CharField(choices=month_choices(), max_length=264)
    month_year = models.ForeignKey(Year,related_name = 'month',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.month) + ' ' + str(self.month_year)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Expense_App:Year")

    class Meta():
        unique_together = [['month','month_year']]

class Expense(models.Model):
    Home_Expense = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Groceries = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Electronics = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Snacks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Other = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    expense_month = models.ForeignKey(Month,related_name = 'expense', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.expense_month) + ' ' + str(self.total)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Expense_App:Year")
```

Forms.py

```
#forms.py
class ExpensesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Expenses
        fields = ('expenses','expense_month')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        month_year_id = kwargs.pop('month_year_id')

        super(ExpensesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['expense_month'].queryset = ExpenseMonth.objects.filter(month_year_id=month_year_id)
```

Views.py

```
#createview for 'expense' model
class ExpenseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Expense
    form_class = ExpenseForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ExpenseCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'month_year_id': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
        return kwargs
```

Urls.py

Update and Delete View will be in these urls (when they are created)

```
#Update and delete views' url
path('year/<int:pk>/<int:pk2>/update_expense/',views.ExpenseUpdateView.as_view(),name = 'update_expense'),
path('year/<int:pk>/<int:pk2>/delete_expense/',views.ExpenseDeleteView.as_view(),name = 'delete_expense'),
```

i checked Django Documentation, but i could find any particular answer for this. Can please Help me out. I searched many questions related to this in stackoverflow and other websites,but couldn't find the answer. Can you please answer this question in this context itself (pls don't reply with a genenral code as, i am new to django and find it difficult to understand general answers)

Thanks in Advance !

The problems are:

1. django takes pk instead pk2 at some places where pk2 need to be used.
2. sometimes updateview and deleteview doesn't even show up, instead raise a page not found error (Desptite correct views and url configuration).
3. Update View Doesn't update the 'expense' model, instead creates a new one.
4. It's behaving very weird. Sometimes Working and sometimes not working.

#UpdateView

```
  class ExpenseUpdateView(UpdateView):
        model = models.Expense
        form_class = ExpenseForm
    
        def get_form_kwargs(self):
            kwargs = super(ExpenseUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
            kwargs.update({'month_year_id': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
            return kwargs
```

#DeleteView

```
    class ExpenseDeleteView(DeleteView):
        model = models.Expense
        success_url = reverse_lazy('Expense_App:Year')
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me, can you tell me what error are you exactly facing?

Comment: The code looks code because, i haven't added updateview and deleteview. I don't want to confuse you by adding my updateview and deleteview, that's why didn't add those. Instead i want you to tell how to write the code....

But anyways, i add my updateview and deleteview in the question